# Traveling to the UK for business: do I need to show proof of funds?

Tags: visas, uk, filipino-citizens, business-travel, proof-of-funds

I'm from Manila, Philippines and might be travelling to UK for business and training purposes for 4 to 6 weeks. Just want to know if we are required to show money or provide bank transactions? (Ex: Tour to S. Korea, you must provide amounts or bank statements)

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: This is not easily answerable without your nationality. Closing for now, but if you edit the question and flag to reopen, we can get you an answer.

Comment: You should probably do some research about UK visas first:
https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/tourist-short-stay-visas

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, you should provide proof of sufficient funds.

Assuming [your intended activities are covered by a stantard visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview), the [section "Documents you must provide"](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide) clearly mentions, among others,

> - evidence that you can support yourself during your trip, eg bank statements or payslips from the last 6 months

Also absolutely read
[Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/32134)

Comment: In case the downvote was more than a revenge-dv please do let me know so that I can improve this answer.